# Why does a Web Search on a custom google search engine return fewer results than a standard search?

Tags: google-search

When I perform a web search on my custom search engine, it returns 2,240 results. When I perform the same search on google.com, I get 8940 results.  I have the custom search engine set to "web search" and not limited to my custom site search.  Why does this happen?

The search:
[cirlex]

1) The [custom search engine](http://www.google.com/custom?hl=en&safe=off&client=google-coop&cof=FORID:13;AH%3aleft;CX%3aAll%2520mas%252Ecom%2520supplier%2520sites;L%3ahttp://www.google.com/intl/en/images/logos/custom_search_logo_sm.gif;LH:30;LP:1;KMBOC%3a%23336699;&adkw=AELymgVrElepF7kLkxPcpMlz26uZUTaePAsryl5yNqAgPI8aYf8r2k9bSufLDyopRKB7fCr-S13m3_rwphfLAGXb9z2r7w9p0mvZs3Dqso1jLhcPniLeK3k&boostcse=0&q=cirlex&btnG=Search&cx=!011093739754940996914%3avlzla7mw9es) set to perform a web search (not a search on the custom sites).

2) The [standard google search](http://%20www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=adhesive%20site%3ahttp://www.fralock.com#hl=en&expIds=17259,27847&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=cirlex&cp=3&qe=Y2ly&qesig=ciu2TKp2y0JCGGu1b-m4Sg&pkc=AFgZ2tkS-Ea1MHPAbu7rh4FIHxoahzmFnTVOAMKJh7gmU_1HNFA2RctT35z7wEVa90Rr99RvHI3ArYImfkJnDYSqMsk96mt0gg&pf=p&sclient=psy&safe=off&aq=0p&aqi=&aql=&oq=cir&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=ca05a7bb65e82229)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is a silly question that no one in the world could answer.  There are discrepancies between every google system that presents data to users, even sometimes on the same screen of their apps.  This is obviously understandable and probably even desirable to google sometimes.  Desirable, because too much data or too much accuracy would allow people to game their systems.

This is my best guess and the only answer I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

There are differences I believe because of the settings found in your custom search engine:

http://www.google.com/cse/

Try to change settings under "Sites" by removing any specific you sites listed and setting "Search the entire web but emphasize included sites." under Basics > Preferences. Changing language options will also change the results you get.

Answer (score -1):

The number of search results shown by both Google and Custom Search Engines (as well as any other search engines) is misleading and is usually way off.